# Shrinkwrap Modifier does absolutely nothing

Tags: modifiers, shrinkwrap

Im making a 3d model of a MiG-29 and it like many other russian aircraft have curves that merge the main fuselage together smoothly. I got a tip from someone that i should use the shrinkwrap modifier to do this instead of doing tedious manual work and I watched a short tutorial as im relatively new to blender and havent used any other modifier besides boolean and mirror yet and it seemed like it was exactly what i was looking for. Upon making a vertex group and targeting it on the shrinkwrap modifier it did nothing, and i have played around with it to no other results.[image: the vertices that do not touch the main fuselage are grouped together and look the same without the modifier applied]

Comment: Hello ! You need to enable the leftmost icon in the modifier header to be able to see the shrinkwrap in effect in edit mode.

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @Gorgious: in my Blender version it works without that icon checked...

Comment: You're right Chris. I would make sure the vertex group is correctly assigned to the edge vertices then.